# How to add times in VBA? Getting Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

Below is some of my code in which I'm trying to add time to a value as part of a For loop. The sheet Parámetros has a cell B1 that only accepts Times (I made sure using the Data Validation tool). So I'm confused why I keep getting the error of "Type Mismatch." I also want to convert the time to a string so that I can concatenate it with some text, and I'm not sure how to do that either.. Any help is appreciated :)

```
Sheets("Parámetros").Range("B1").Value = Sheets("Parámetros").Range("B1").Value + Time(0, 5, 0)
```

Comment: .Value of a cell doesn't return the type "time" unless you convert it first. I'd create new variables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
Time(0, 5, 0)
```

with:

```
TimeSerial(0, 5, 0)
```